# Sequelize object is not a function

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express, sequelize.js

I am working from this [repo](https://github.com/sequelize/express-example) and trying to convert it over to PostgreSQL here is my error:

```
/home/otis/Developer/Shipwrecked/Hatchway/node_modules/sequelize/lib/sequelize.js:601
    this.importCache[path] = defineCall(this, DataTypes);
                             ^
TypeError: object is not a function
    at Sequelize.import (/home/otis/Developer/Shipwrecked/Hatchway/node_modules/sequelize/lib/sequelize.js:601:30)
    at db.sequelize (/home/otis/Developer/Shipwrecked/Hatchway/models/index.js:15:37)
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/otis/Developer/Shipwrecked/Hatchway/models/index.js:14:6)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/otis/Developer/Shipwrecked/Hatchway/app.js:10:12)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/otis/Developer/Shipwrecked/Hatchway/bin/www:7:11)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
```

Here is the code that is causing the error (models/index.js):

```
var fs        = require("fs");
var path      = require("path");
var Sequelize = require("sequelize");
var env       = process.env.NODE_ENV || "development";
var config    = require(__dirname + '/../config.json')[env];
var sequelize = new Sequelize(config.database, config.username, config.password, config);
var db        = {};

fs
    .readdirSync(__dirname)
    .filter(function(file) {
        return (file.indexOf(".") !== 0) && (file !== "index.js");
    })
    .forEach(function(file) {
        var model = sequelize.import(path.join(__dirname, file));
        db[model.name] = model;
    });

Object.keys(db).forEach(function(modelName) {
    if ("associate" in db[modelName]) {
        db[modelName].associate(db);
    }
});

db.sequelize = sequelize;
db.Sequelize = Sequelize;

module.exports = db;
```

If I comment out the following lines the error stops:

```
fs
    .readdirSync(__dirname)
    .filter(function(file) {
        return (file.indexOf(".") !== 0) && (file !== "index.js");
    })
    .forEach(function(file) {
        var model = sequelize.import(path.join(__dirname, file));
        db[model.name] = model;
    });
```

`Node.js` errors are not my strong point so I am not really sure what is going, on I can also post my `config.json` if that is needed?

Comment: paste your `models/index.js` file

Comment: The middle snippet is the index.js

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If we look at the [code imports](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/blob/465aa4cb4706bd24d288f8e59d5f970e927df0ca/lib/sequelize.js):

```
 if (!this.importCache[path]) {
    var defineCall = (arguments.length > 1 ? arguments[1] : require(path));
    this.importCache[path] = defineCall(this, DataTypes);
  }
```

...it will be understood that it looks like a folder with the models have a file that is not a valid model file and generally correct module. Accordingly, in an attempt to activate it via the "desirable" get errors. Check folder models.

Comment: Cheers, figured this out just before I saw your answer :)